# Dynamically accelerating odometer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm trying to come up with a striking visual way to display a number. The number in question, based on the settings, can vary between 0 and 10,000,000 or so. So initially I had thought I would set up an odometer in Javascript that would just add up to the final number. I did this with a simple setInterval function, but the problem is, for numbers greater than a few thousand or so, even with zero delay, it takes waaaay too long. As one would expect.

What I'd really like is a function that could look at the total number in question and adjust how the adding of the odometer went based on that. That is, it would take some sort of estimated total number (say, 10 seconds), and then figure out how many it needed to add with each interval to make it in that amount of time. It would also use random numbers to some degree so it isn't just a "chunky" adding of a million each second.

Here is the original code, which is pretty obvious and straightforward:

```
var totalNumber;
var currentNumber;
var changeInterval = 1; //even 0 is too slow

//later in a function scope 

        interval = setInterval(function() {
                updateNumber();
            }, changeInterval);

//later
function updateNumber() {
    currentNumber++;
    if(currentNumber>=totalNumber) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    document.getElementById("theNumber").innerHTML = currentNumber;
}
```

I'm having trouble conceptualizing a non-lame way to implement this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the current number based on how long it has gone since last iteration. I made a simple example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hwFJm/

```
var number = 452131,
    delay = 20,
    totalTime = 10000;

$(function() {
    count(number, delay, totalTime, $('#counter'));    
});

function count(total, delay, totalTime, element, decimals) {
    var number = 0,
        startTime = newTime = new Date();

    decimals = decimals || 2;

    element.text(number);

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        newTime = new Date();
        number = Math.min(total * ((newTime - startTime) / totalTime), total);

        number = Math.floor(number * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);

        element.text(number);
        if(number >= total) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thank you! This is basically what I wanted, I was just having a hard time conceptualizing it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you define

```
var totalTime = 10000; // 10 seconds
```

you know that the number of updates you need is:

```
var numberOfTicks = totalTime/changeInterval;
```

and the amount you need to increase currentNumber at each interval is:

```
var increment = totalNumber/numberOfTicks
```

as long as you start from zero.
In order to avoid roundoff problems, rather than increasing, use a counter and set the value each time:

```
function updateNumber() {
    updateCounter++;
    currentNumber = increment * updateCounter;
    if(currentNumber>=totalNumber) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    ....
```

and I don't know I forgot something, but it should be enough to get it going.